# Can I use Angular2 service in DOM addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, angular, events, dom

Issue: When I try to call service within addEventListener, service seems to be empty.

Html:

`<div id="_file0">`

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class FilesService {
  constructor(private http : Http) { }

}
```

Component:

```
export class NoteComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private filesService : FilesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addEvent(document.getElementById("_file0"));
  }
  addEvent(div){
    console.log("tag1", this.filesService);
    div.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log("tag2", this.filesService);
      });
  }

}
```

Console output:

```
tag1 FilesService {http: Http}
tag2 undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this code to maintain `this` context

```
div.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("tag2", this.filesService);
});
```

Additional info: this is called Arrow function or lamda function. What it actually does is when Typescript compiles your code into javascript, it creates another `_this` variable to store the real `this` and whenever you call `this` it gets replaces by `_this`.

That's why your original code gets compile, `this` is `undefined` because it was the context of `click` event not your Angular component.

Comment: To clarify, `function() {...` changes what `this` is, and an arrow function `() => {...` does not change `this`.